# If inside foreach inside for inside for

Tags: php

I have a problem;

When I do this:

```
<?php
$ncarts = $_POST["ncarts"];
$npedras = $_POST["npedras"];
$quantidade_sorteada = $_GET["quantidade_sorteada"];
echo $quantidade_sorteada;
?>
```

I have the correct output using echo.
But, when I do this:

```
<?php
$ncarts = $_POST["ncarts"];
$npedras = $_POST["npedras"];
$quantidade_sorteada = $_GET["quantidade_sorteada"];

echo $quantidade_sorteada;

for ($p=1; $p<=$ncarts; $p++) {
    $numeros_cartela$p = file ("cartela{$p}.txt"); 
}

for ($k=1; $k<=$quantidade_sorteada; $k++) {
    $sorted$k = $_GET["numero$k"]; 
}

for ($p=1; $p<=$ncarts; $p++) {
    $contador_pontos_cartela$p = 0;
    for ($g=1; $g<=$quantidade_sorteada; $g++) {
        foreach ($numeros_cartela$p as $w) {
            if ($w == $sorted$g) {
                $contador_pontos_cartela$p += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

for ($oi=1; $oi<=$ncarts; $oi++) {
    echo $contador_pontos_cartela$oi;
}
?>
```

The first echo stop to work. It shows me that I have a prgramming error on the second part of the code. But I can't find that.

Someone help me??
Thanks

---

NEW CODE:

```
<?php
$ncarts = $_POST["ncarts"];
$npedras = $_POST["npedras"];
$quantidade_sorteada = $_GET["quantidade_sorteada"];

echo $quantidade_sorteada;

for ($p=1; $p<=$ncarts; $p++) {
$numeros_cartela[$p] = file ("cartela{$p}.txt"); 
}

for ($k=1; $k<=$quantidade_sorteada; $k++) {
$sorted[$k] = $_GET["numero$k"]; 
}

for ($p=1; $p<=$ncarts; $p++) {
$contador_pontos_cartela{$p} = 0;
 for ($g=1; $g<=$quantidade_sorteada; $g++) {
foreach ($numeros_cartela[$p] as $w) {

if ($w == $sorted[$g]){
$contador_pontos_cartela{$p} += 1;
}

}
}
}

for ($oi=1; $oi<=$ncarts; $oi++)  {
echo $contador_pontos_cartela{$oi};

}

?>
```

Comment: If it tells you you have an error, please post the specific error.

Comment: I suppose "programming error" is confidential?

Comment: `It shows me that I have a prgramming error ` You expect us to guess the error, right?

Comment: I'm gonna guess that the error was something like this: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' on line X`, corresponding to `echo $contador_pontos_cartela$oi;`. Voting to close.

Comment: I have a error. I've failed on the programming. Understand?!

Comment: But, the php doesn't returns any error.

Comment: See the [PHP tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info), in particular the section `I have a typical "does not work" problem. What should I do before asking a question?`. This will help you debug this type of problem in future.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot generate variables like this:

```
$numeros_cartela$p
```

If you need a variable that ends with a number, you would have to do:

```
$numeros_cartela{$p}
```

But you would be a lot better off to use arrays:

```
// initialize the array
$numeros_cartela = array();
...
// use the array in your loop
$numeros_cartela[$p] = ...
```

The same for all other instances where you do it like this.

Comment: I have arrays here. $numeros_cartela{$p} = file ("cartela{$p}.txt");

Comment: What I've thought: $numeros_cartela1 = line 1 of the cartela1.txt

Comment: @WithoutNameZin No, `$numeros_cartela{$p}` is a normal variable. You could use `$numeros_cartela[$p] = file ("cartela{$p}.txt");` to generate a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: The $numeros_cartela1 will be equal an array with the lines of the file cartela1.txt, or not ?

Comment: @WithoutNameZin Yes, but if you use `$numeros_cartela[1]` you will be able to easily loop over all files / `$numeros_cartela`.

Comment: I've wrote like this before, but I thought: and the 0 index of array ?? Will it be empty ?

Comment: @WithoutNameZin It will not exist, but does that matter? You can use any kind of numeric or textual key for an array. Using a `foreach` will loop over your complete array, regardless of the (type of...) keys.

Comment: Hey, may you look at the new code ? Tell me if was it that was you talking about.

Comment: @WithoutNameZin I would do the same for `$contador_pontos_cartela` and initialize my arrays.

Comment: Like this: $numeros_cartela = array();
$sorted = array();
$contador_pontos_cartela = array();  ?

Comment: I have a basic doubt, in this loop: for ($p=1; $p<=$ncarts; $p++) {
$contador_pontos_cartela[$p] = 0;
 for ($g=1; $g<=$quantidade_sorteada; $g++) {
foreach ($numeros_cartela[$p] as $w) {

if ($w == $sorted[$g]){
$contador_pontos_cartela[$p] += 1;
}
}
}
} When finish the foreach and the $g will increase by one, the foreach returns to the outset or it will be the last value of the array? When I've done the code, I supposed to It would to the outset.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in lines like

```
$numeros_cartela$p = ...;
```

PHP doesn't allow such syntax. Use arrays:

```
$numeros_cartela[$p] = ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables can't be created like $numeros_cartela$p and $sorted$k.

You can use the array to store the values and then iterate them to get the values.